# Replace a record in a table when looking up that record in another table with python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

Lets say I have a dataframe that exists df1. In one of the columns I have records that I want to replace with the username that exists in another data frame.

So if column B has your computer hostname in it and df2 has your hostname with username. I want to replace column B with your username. I am thinking it has to do with pandas replace but my mind seems fried.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Merge the dataframes on the column that the two dataframes share, so "hostname" is this case.

Comment: Is there a way to do it and still keep the records that did not exist in df2. 

When I tested the merge it only kept the records that existed in both dataframes. I have logins and hostnames that exists in column B. I just want to replace the hostnames with the usernames from df2 while still keeping the original logins plus the new replaced hostnames.

Comment: merge the other way around?

Comment: Sort of works. Looks cleaner but still drops the username. I wonder if I should extract the data types that don't match up into another dataframe, change up the original and then add the two dataframes together. 

I wonder if the map() function would work better?

Comment: One way to find out ;)